# Google groups mail conversation retrieval approach

Tags: migration

Since I'm working to collect the google group mail conversation using group unique mail id. but there is no google-API approach. Kindly give me any ideas/approaches to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do it with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)

For this you need to

- use the method [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)
- authenticate with a userId that is member of the Google group
- set `userId` to `me`
- set the query parameter `q` to `to:EMAIL-OF-THE-GROUP`

Whereby `EMAIL-OF-THE-GROUP` is to be replaced with your actual group email.

This query returns you the emails in a user's inbox that were addressed to the group email rather than the user's personal email.

Comment: I have tried this approach but if I enabled the "No Email" subscription of EMAIL-OF-THE-GROUP then group mails null response after these changes. does google has any specific API for this ?

Comment: What do you mean by ` "No Email" subscription of EMAIL-OF-THE-GROUP`? Unofrtunately there is no specific API for getting the mail conversation in a group.

Comment: We have an option like a subscription on each group like Each email, Digest, Abridged, No Email. When we set "No Email" then logged user doesn't receive any email of group's in Gmail. In this case, we can't able to get mail conversations in "users.messages.list"

Comment: The subscription is individual for each user - you can set up a dummy user and set his subscription to "each  email" and retrieve the Google Groups messags for this user. Unfortunately there is no other API to do so in a more direct way.

Comment: sorry for the delay response. it was worked fine and thank you lot.